# Linux directory becoming a clear plain text file

Tags: linux, filesystems, filesystem-corruption

Did anyone encounter this before? I have a directory called opt which is working previously. Last few days ago, i tried to expand LVM size by using off-line expand. It show success but with some error message. After expanding, tried reboot and encounter kernel panic. Run rescue disk and check that some folders is not a directory anymore.

```
*root@Microknoppix:/mnt/sde1# ls -l opt
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 11702 Nov 11 2010 opt*
```

By runnning cat,

```
*root@Microknoppix:/mnt/sde1# cat opt
name TB
spacewidth 7806
pcltypeface 4101
pclproportional 1
pclweight 3
pclstyle 0
ligatures fi fl ff ffi ffl 0
kernpairs
L V -3414
P . -4389
P , -4389
V A -4878
A V -4878
T o -2925
T r -1461
T c -2439
```

⋮

```
/L  17565,18045 2   51944
/l  7317,18090  2   51960
a"  13173,19065 2   51933
ho  13173,513,4413  0   51934
vZ  17565,24795 2   51802
IJ  23904,18045,405 2   51942
root@Microknoppix:/mnt/sde1#*
```

Is there any possible chances that I can convert back to directory? I had important files in the folder and need to be recover.

Comment: Is /opt a mountpoint in your setup? That looks like opt just hasn't been mounted and there's a spec file there (some init systems use those to mount things).

Comment: opt is not mounted at the first place. There are a few folders that are effected and opt is one of them. can we convert the file to folder? I run df -h, LVM still show the actual used space.